# htaccess remove duplicity .php and /

Tags: .htaccess

Please help me with remove duplicity in .htaccess for all sites

redirect: *.php and /

```
example:
http://www.masazekonice.cz/o-mne/ > http://www.masazekonice.cz/o-mne
http://www.masazekonice.cz/o-mne.php > http://www.masazekonice.cz/o-mne

#my-htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^masazekonice\.cz$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.masazekonice.cz/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://masazekonice.cz/$1 [R=301]      

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php    [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^masazekonice\.cz$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.masazekonice.cz/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://masazekonice.cz/$1 [R=301,L]      

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.+)(?:/|\.php)(?:\?|\ )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php    [L]
```